# Update Array with dynamically generated values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm very new to JavaScript, so I'm having a hard time with this relatively simple problem:

I wrote a function that dynamically adds or removes dropdown fields to the DOM if the user clicks the add or remove button. So far so good, everything is working fine until here.

Now I want to collect the data in an Array to send it to the api.
With the following code I can collect it, but I have a hard time to figure out how I can remove specific values from the array.

```
<div class="container mt-2" id="stores">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h2>Marktet</h2>
                                    <div class="col-form-label storesHint">Select at least one market</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="form">
                                <div>
                                    <div id="addAnotherMarket">
                                    <div class="marketRow">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="market" name="market">
                                      <option value="1"> market1</option>
                                      <option value="2"> market2</option>
                                      <option value="3"> market3</option>
                                      <option value="4"> market4</option>
                                      <option value="5"> market5</option>
                              
                                    </select>
                                    <input class="deleteButton" type="button" id="remove" value="" style="display: none; font-family: FontAwesome, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <div class="addBtnContainer">
                                        <div class="centerBtn">
                                        <a class=" button btn_gray buttonWithIcon" id="add">
                                            <i class=" fa fa-plus icn" id="btnIcon" style="font-size: 16px;" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                                            <span class="btnText spn" style="top:0px !important">Add another market</span>  
                                        </a> 
                                        </div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let index = 0;
  let store = {};
  let stores = [];
  var oldValue = [];
  window.Stores = stores;

  //set initial value for the first dropdown element
  store = { "store_id": parseInt($('#market').val(), 10) };
  stores.push(store);
  oldValue[index] = store;
  //update value if user changes first element
  $('#market').on('change', function () {
    store = { "store_id": parseInt($(this).val(), 10) };
    var eleIndex = stores.indexOf(oldValue[index]);
    if (eleIndex !== -1) {
      stores.splice(eleIndex, 1, store);
      oldValue[index] = store;
    }
  });
  //add a new dropwdown element 
  $("#add").click(function () {
    index++;
    $(this).parent().parent().before($("#form").clone().attr("id", "form" + index));
    $("#form" + index + " :input").each(function () {
      $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + index);
      $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + index);
    });

    //set initial value of the new dropdown element    
    store = { "store_id": parseInt($('#market' + index).val(), 10) };
    stores.push(store);
    oldValue[index] = store;
    //set new value if user changes value
    $('#market' + index).on('change', function () {
      store = { "store_id": parseInt($(this).val(), 10) };
      var eleIndex = stores.indexOf(oldValue[index]);
      if (eleIndex !== -1) {
        stores.splice(eleIndex, 1, store);
        oldValue[index] = store;
      }
    });

    //add remove button    
    $("#remove" + index).css("display", "inline-flex");
    $(".marketRow").css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'align-items': 'center',
      'margin-top': '5px'
    });

    //if user clicks remove button delete value from array
    $("#remove" + index).click(function () {
      var eleIndex = stores.indexOf({ "store_id": parseInt($('#market' + index).val(), 10) });
      if (index !== -1) {
        stores.splice(eleIndex, 1);
        oldValue.splice(eleIndex);
      }
      $(this).closest("div").remove();

    });
  });


});
```

The following code also outputs -1 always, so I think indexOf makes no sense.

var eleIndex = stores.indexOf({"store_id": parseInt($('#market' + index).val(), 10)});

EDIT: I updated the post with the HTML part as requested. In short: When clicking on button(#add) div(#form) will be cloned, remove button will be added, and id's will be updated with index.
Values of all these selects will be stored and updated in the stores array. I just can't delete them.

I have also provided a working jsfiddel https://jsfiddle.net/proach1995/h1gtmyen/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you add the skeleton of the HTML code you are using? I'm trying to visualise what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks @DanNagle I have provided a jsfiddle to clearify what I want to archieve

Answer (score 0):

With plain js you can add class to the dropdown you wish to collect from. in the code below it will build the array only if value was selected.
if you use jQuery you can replace `document.querySelectorAll('.store');` with `$('.store');`

```js
function saveArray() {
  const selected = document.querySelectorAll('.store');
  const stores = [];
  selected.forEach(prop => {
    if (!!prop.value) {
      stores.push({store_id: parseInt(prop.value, 10)})
    }
  });
  console.log(stores);
}
```

```html
<select class="store">
  <option disabled selected value>select value</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="store">
  <option disabled selected value>select value</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<select class="store">
  <option disabled selected value>select value</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<button onclick="saveArray()">save array</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. In my case input fields are added dynamically, so I think I can't apply your answer in the right way. I have added a jsfiddle in the original post to clearify what exactly I want to do.